# Prometheus metric with dynamic label value

Tags: prometheus

I have a prometheus metric representing application build stability, then value can be from 0 to 100 - I would like to map the current value with the application build number.
When the build is ready, I want to update the build number on the metric and the metric value with the stability value.

If I add a buildNumber label to the metric, then a new metric is created each time when I update the metric and the label value.
Is there any better way to handle this in Prometheus?

Update:
There will be more applications and I would like to run queries like what was the average stability per application by the last 10 builds

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not a new metric that's created but a new time-series is recorded for each new combination of labels that are applied to a metric.

IIUC, a solution would be to use one label to describe the application and another to represent the build number.

Then you can always query by the application value to see the stability value.

i.e.

To measure an application's stability:

```
build_stability{application="my-billion-dollar-app"}
```

To measure an cross-application build's stability:

```
build_stability{build="alpha"}
```

Comment: Thanks, however it is not clear how I can map the stability with the build number. Like I would like to know what was the stabilty if application X by the build number Y

Comment: You can combine labels: `build_stability{application="my-billion-dollar-app,build="alpha"}`